# How can i create a stand-alone list with append for each iteration?

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension, nested-loops

**I get the following raw data via an API:**

```
[{'landing_id': '5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q', 'token': '5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q', 'response_id': '5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q', 'landed_at': '2021-08-27T13:50:18Z', 'submitted_at': '2021-08-27T13:50:49Z', 'metadata': {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36', 'platform': 'other', 'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL?typeform-source=localhost', 'network_id': 'd9b4f41014', 'browser': 'default'}, 'hidden': {}, 'calculated': {'score': 0}, 'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu', 'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Asdflasdfjkasdf'}, {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ', 'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'ASdflasdfkö'}, {'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C', 'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5', 'type': 'email'}, 'type': 'email', 'email': 'philipp@ganster.com'}]}, {'landing_id': 'mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1', 'token': 'mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1', 'response_id': 'mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1', 'landed_at': '2021-08-24T13:33:01Z', 'submitted_at': '2021-08-24T13:33:16Z', 'metadata': {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36', 'platform': 'other', 'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL', 'network_id': '1b607e2e2c', 'browser': 'default'}, 'hidden': {}, 'calculated': {'score': 0}, 'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu', 'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Alles cool'}, {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ', 'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Cool cooli cooli'}, {'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C', 'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5', 'type': 'email'}, 'type': 'email', 'email': 'cool@cool.de'}]}, {'landing_id': 'v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj', 'token': 'v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj', 'response_id': 'v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj', 'landed_at': '2021-08-24T12:35:25Z', 'submitted_at': '2021-08-24T12:35:52Z', 'metadata': {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36', 'platform': 'other', 'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL', 'network_id': '1b607e2e2c', 'browser': 'default'}, 'hidden': {}, 'calculated': {'score': 0}, 'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu', 'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Wir sind die Besten weltweit'}, {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ', 'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton'}, {'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C', 'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5', 'type': 'email'}, 'type': 'email', 'email': 'elisa@andyduke.com'}]}, {'landing_id': '9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm', 'token': '9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm', 'response_id': '9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm', 'landed_at': '2021-08-17T19:33:29Z', 'submitted_at': '2021-08-17T19:33:47Z', 'metadata': {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36', 'platform': 'other', 'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL', 'network_id': '8b083c318f', 'browser': 'default'}, 'hidden': {}, 'calculated': {'score': 0}, 'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu', 'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Wir haben keins'}, {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ', 'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Nicht so gut'}, {'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C', 'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5', 'type': 'email'}, 'type': 'email', 'email': 'ganster95@gmail.com'}]}, {'landing_id': '6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc', 'token': '6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc', 'response_id': '6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc', 'landed_at': '2021-08-16T15:25:52Z', 'submitted_at': '2021-08-16T15:26:44Z', 'metadata': {'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36', 'platform': 'other', 'referer': 'https://5elebf29vtz.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL', 'network_id': 'f46ac8439a', 'browser': 'default'}, 'hidden': {}, 'calculated': {'score': 0}, 'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu', 'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Wir sind beraten, installieren und konfigurieren die besten Solarzellen'}, {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ', 'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08', 'type': 'short_text'}, 'type': 'text', 'text': 'Sehr druckvoll, aber auch liebevoll. Wir sind die Besten mit Herz und Seele.'}, {'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C', 'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5', 'type': 'email'}, 'type': 'email', 'email': 'philipp.ganster95@gmail.com'}]}]
```

**For better reading reasons**, i used the pprint package, to show the data in a structured way (**However**, the data above is used for my function since it is a list and the pprint package illustrates it as an dictionary - so this could be a little bit misleading):

```
{'items': [{'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu',
                                   'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Asdflasdfjkasdf',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ',
                                   'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'ASdflasdfkö',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'email': 'philipp@ganster.com',
                         'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C',
                                   'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5',
                                   'type': 'email'},
                         'type': 'email'}],
            'calculated': {'score': 0},
            'hidden': {},
            'landed_at': '2021-08-27T13:50:18Z',
            'landing_id': '5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q',
            'metadata': {'browser': 'default',
                         'network_id': 'd9b4f41014',
                         'platform': 'other',
                         'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL?typeform-source=localhost',
                         'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X '
                                       '10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                                       'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 '
                                       'Safari/537.36'},
            'response_id': '5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q',
            'submitted_at': '2021-08-27T13:50:49Z',
            'token': '5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q'},
           {'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu',
                                   'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Alles cool',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ',
                                   'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Cool cooli cooli',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'email': 'cool@cool.de',
                         'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C',
                                   'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5',
                                   'type': 'email'},
                         'type': 'email'}],
            'calculated': {'score': 0},
            'hidden': {},
            'landed_at': '2021-08-24T13:33:01Z',
            'landing_id': 'mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1',
            'metadata': {'browser': 'default',
                         'network_id': '1b607e2e2c',
                         'platform': 'other',
                         'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL',
                         'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X '
                                       '10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                                       'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 '
                                       'Safari/537.36'},
            'response_id': 'mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1',
            'submitted_at': '2021-08-24T13:33:16Z',
            'token': 'mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1'},
           {'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu',
                                   'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Wir sind die Besten weltweit',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ',
                                   'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'email': 'elisa@andyduke.com',
                         'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C',
                                   'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5',
                                   'type': 'email'},
                         'type': 'email'}],
            'calculated': {'score': 0},
            'hidden': {},
            'landed_at': '2021-08-24T12:35:25Z',
            'landing_id': 'v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj',
            'metadata': {'browser': 'default',
                         'network_id': '1b607e2e2c',
                         'platform': 'other',
                         'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL',
                         'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X '
                                       '10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                                       'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 '
                                       'Safari/537.36'},
            'response_id': 'v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj',
            'submitted_at': '2021-08-24T12:35:52Z',
            'token': 'v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj'},
           {'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu',
                                   'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Wir haben keins',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ',
                                   'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Nicht so gut',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'email': 'ganster95@gmail.com',
                         'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C',
                                   'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5',
                                   'type': 'email'},
                         'type': 'email'}],
            'calculated': {'score': 0},
            'hidden': {},
            'landed_at': '2021-08-17T19:33:29Z',
            'landing_id': '9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm',
            'metadata': {'browser': 'default',
                         'network_id': '8b083c318f',
                         'platform': 'other',
                         'referer': 'https://form.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL',
                         'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X '
                                       '10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                                       'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 '
                                       'Safari/537.36'},
            'response_id': '9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm',
            'submitted_at': '2021-08-17T19:33:47Z',
            'token': '9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm'},
           {'answers': [{'field': {'id': 'rwNldsS8H1Uu',
                                   'ref': '01FD00Z0842DNV2F7TV5S034FB',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Wir sind beraten, installieren und '
                                 'konfigurieren die besten Solarzellen',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'field': {'id': 'HmiYDva4iYTJ',
                                   'ref': '005e2b9d-2ffa-4102-b8ad-7f5245677b08',
                                   'type': 'short_text'},
                         'text': 'Sehr druckvoll, aber auch liebevoll. Wir '
                                 'sind die Besten mit Herz und Seele.',
                         'type': 'text'},
                        {'email': 'philipp.ganster95@gmail.com',
                         'field': {'id': 'zCNV4nksvT7C',
                                   'ref': '2bdaadb8-e4ed-4cb3-bdf6-9c93c2a70ed5',
                                   'type': 'email'},
                         'type': 'email'}],
            'calculated': {'score': 0},
            'hidden': {},
            'landed_at': '2021-08-16T15:25:52Z',
            'landing_id': '6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc',
            'metadata': {'browser': 'default',
                         'network_id': 'f46ac8439a',
                         'platform': 'other',
                         'referer': 'https://5elebf29vtz.typeform.com/to/znd02BPL',
                         'user_agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X '
                                       '10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                                       'like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 '
                                       'Safari/537.36'},
            'response_id': '6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc',
            'submitted_at': '2021-08-16T15:26:44Z',
            'token': '6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc'}],
 'page_count': 1,
 'total_items': 5}
```

**My use case:**

I want to retrieve the response_id, the user's email and all the answers for each response. For that i already wrote the following function (the RESPS variable contains all the data above):

```
def structure_response (RESPS): # returns response ID, user e-mail and answers
    
    answers = []
    count = 1
        
    for i in RESPS: # loops through list of responses containing dictionaries
        
        for key, value in i.items():
            
            if key == "response_id": # returns response_id
                response_id = value
        
            if key == "answers": # returns email
                user_email = value[-1]["email"]
            
                for j in value: # returns answers | value is a list containing dictionaries                 
                    for key, value in j.items():
                        if key == "text":
                            answers.append(value)
        
        #Print Output
        print("Response {} :".format(count))
        print("Response ID: " + str(response_id))
        print("User's E-Mail Adress: " + str(user_email))
        print("Answers : " + str(answers))                   
        print("\n")
        count += 1
        


# Call Function
structure_response(RESPS)
```

**Output:**

```
Response 1 :
Response ID: 5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q
User's E-Mail Adress: philipp@ganster.com
Answers : ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö']


Response 2 :
Response ID: mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1
User's E-Mail Adress: cool@cool.de
Answers : ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö', 'Alles cool', 'Cool cooli cooli']


Response 3 :
Response ID: v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj
User's E-Mail Adress: elisa@andyduke.com
Answers : ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö', 'Alles cool', 'Cool cooli cooli', 'Wir sind die Besten weltweit', 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton']


Response 4 :
Response ID: 9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm
User's E-Mail Adress: ganster95@gmail.com
Answers : ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö', 'Alles cool', 'Cool cooli cooli', 'Wir sind die Besten weltweit', 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton', 'Wir haben keins', 'Nicht so gut']


Response 5 :
Response ID: 6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc
User's E-Mail Adress: philipp.ganster95@gmail.com
Answers : ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö', 'Alles cool', 'Cool cooli cooli', 'Wir sind die Besten weltweit', 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton', 'Wir haben keins', 'Nicht so gut', 'Wir sind beraten, installieren und konfigurieren die besten Solarzellen', 'Sehr druckvoll, aber auch liebevoll. Wir sind die Besten mit Herz und Seele.']
```

**My Problem:**

Right now, the answers list appends with each iteration for each response. However, i want to stop the appending after every response.

**My desired output:**

```
Response 1 :
    Response ID: 5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q
    User's E-Mail Adress: philipp@ganster.com
    Answers : ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö']
    
    
    Response 2 :
    Response ID: mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1
    User's E-Mail Adress: cool@cool.de
    Answers : ['Alles cool', 'Cool cooli cooli']
    
    
    Response 3 :
    Response ID: v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj
    User's E-Mail Adress: elisa@andyduke.com
    Answers : ['Wir sind die Besten weltweit', 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton']
    
    
    Response 4 :
    Response ID: 9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm
    User's E-Mail Adress: ganster95@gmail.com
    Answers : ['Wir haben keins', 'Nicht so gut']
    
    
    Response 5 :
    Response ID: 6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc
    User's E-Mail Adress: philipp.ganster95@gmail.com
    Answers : ['Wir sind beraten, installieren und konfigurieren die besten Solarzellen', 'Sehr druckvoll, aber auch liebevoll. Wir sind die Besten mit Herz und Seele.']
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `dct` is your dictionary from the question, you can do:

```py
for i, d in enumerate(dct["items"], 1):
    print("Response {}:".format(i))
    print("Response ID: {}".format(d["response_id"]))
    print(
        "User's E-Mail Adress: {}".format(
            next(v for v in d["answers"] if v["type"] == "email")["email"]
        )
    )
    print("Answers: ", [v["text"] for v in d["answers"] if v["type"] == "text"])
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Response 1:
Response ID: 5rjqwlrxzzcve5s7ip05rjqw531fyk9q
User's E-Mail Adress: philipp@ganster.com
Answers:  ['Asdflasdfjkasdf', 'ASdflasdfkö']

Response 2:
Response ID: mnpxvbgbmgi0aut64g7mnpxvb1a66lb1
User's E-Mail Adress: cool@cool.de
Answers:  ['Alles cool', 'Cool cooli cooli']

Response 3:
Response ID: v2szjmf3by92rzpcyt6gxzv2szjmf3gj
User's E-Mail Adress: elisa@andyduke.com
Answers:  ['Wir sind die Besten weltweit', 'Sehr freundlich aber hart im Ton']

Response 4:
Response ID: 9nquhgyp7dtddqxzj8mg9nquh5tsernm
User's E-Mail Adress: ganster95@gmail.com
Answers:  ['Wir haben keins', 'Nicht so gut']

Response 5:
Response ID: 6y29hqnt2kr3nwtun6y292j5ede7kluc
User's E-Mail Adress: philipp.ganster95@gmail.com
Answers:  ['Wir sind beraten, installieren und konfigurieren die besten Solarzellen', 'Sehr druckvoll, aber auch liebevoll. Wir sind die Besten mit Herz und Seele.']
```

---

EDIT: If you have a list `lst`:

```py
for i, d in enumerate(lst, 1):
    print("Response {}:".format(i))
    print("Response ID: {}".format(d["response_id"]))
    print(
        "User's E-Mail Adress: {}".format(
            next(v for v in d["answers"] if v["type"] == "email")["email"]
        )
    )
    print("Answers: ", [v["text"] for v in d["answers"] if v["type"] == "text"])
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej for your answers! Please see the changes above in my question. I think it was misleading, since the raw data from the API is a list. Hence, the use of the pprint package it makes it look like a dictionary. Furthermore, i have troubles understanding your code. Could you maybe stick a little bit more to mine? If not, i will try to understand it.

Comment: if you have the time, maybe you could comment you code for clarification just a little bit. I totally understand how the first to prints work (counter and response_id) but i have trouble understanding the last two prints for the mail and answers. Especially the "next" statement and the "v for v" loop. For what is next used for and what does v for v do?

Comment: @philuix The [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) call is used here to find item that has `"type"` equal to `"email"`. `v for v in d["answers"]` is iterating over items in list `"answers"` until the `type == "email" ` is found.